# What is the reaction mechanism of a selective catalytic reaction with urea?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reference-request

What is the reaction mechanism of the following reaction:

$$\ce{4NO + 2(NH2)2CO + O2 -> 4N2 + 4H2O + 2CO2}$$

I expect that the catalyst is vanadium oxide and titanium oxide.
Where can I find a detailed description of the reaction mechanism?

Comment: Have you consulted any sources before posting here, like SciFinder, Web of Knowledge, Google Scholar? I'd assume that there is a special interest in these systems, but if wouldn't be totally surprised if extensive mechanistic studies are not yet done due to the complexity of the reaction.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/S0920-5861(00)00299-6; https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cattod.2006.08.018.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After researching this topic, I've found the mechanism to be:
[image]